# How to create a triple overlapping border with CSS?

Tags: html, css, border

I wanted to achieve triple border like below image.

[image]

I have tried below solution but, the corners are still looking different. it is not overlapping.

```css
.dtborder {
  position: relative;
  border: 5px solid red;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background: #f8f8f8;
  padding: 30px;
}

.dtborder:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  border: 5px solid blue;
}

.dtborder:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  right: 15px;
  border: 5px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="dtborder ">This text appears inside a double bracket bordered div where you can control the gap between border lines.</div>
```

See this : https://jsfiddle.net/kajh1odv/1/

Comment: I'd use `border-image`..probably easier.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can consider `linear-gradient` that you can scale **indefinitely** to have as many border as you want. It may look complicated but you will see that all the gradient will have the same size (`4px`) so `[100% 4px]` for the horizontal ones and `[4px 100%]` for the vertical ones. Then for the position we remove/add `8px` *(or any value)* each time to offest between each gradient.

```css
.dtborder {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  background:
  /*First border*/
  linear-gradient(red,red) 0 100%/100%  4px, /*Bottom*/
  linear-gradient(red,red) 0 0/100%  4px ,   /*Top*/
  linear-gradient(red,red) 0 0/4px 100% ,    /*left*/
  linear-gradient(red,red) 100% 0/4px 100%,  /*right*/
  /*Second border*/
  linear-gradient(blue,blue) 0 calc(100% - 8px)/100%  4px ,
  linear-gradient(blue,blue) 0 8px/100%  4px,
  linear-gradient(blue,blue) 8px 0/4px 100%,
  linear-gradient(blue,blue) calc(100% - 8px) 0/4px 100%,
  /*third border*/
  linear-gradient(green,green) 0 calc(100% - 16px)/100%  4px,
  linear-gradient(green,green) 0 16px/100%  4px,
  linear-gradient(green,green) 16px 0/4px 100%,
  linear-gradient(green,green) calc(100% - 16px) 0/4px 100%;
  /*And so on ...*/
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dtborder ">This text appears inside a double bracket bordered div where you can control the gap between border lines.</div>
```

You can optimize the code like this:

```css
.dtborder {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  background:
  /*First border*/
  linear-gradient(red,red) 0 100%,
  linear-gradient(red,red) 0 0,
  linear-gradient(red,red) 0 0,
  linear-gradient(red,red) 100% 0,
  /*Second border*/
  linear-gradient(blue,blue) 0 calc(100% - 8px),
  linear-gradient(blue,blue) 8px 0,
  linear-gradient(blue,blue) 0 8px,
  linear-gradient(blue,blue) calc(100% - 8px) 0,
  /*third border*/
  linear-gradient(green,green) 0 calc(100% - 16px),
  linear-gradient(green,green) 16px 0,
  linear-gradient(green,green) 0 16px,
  linear-gradient(green,green) calc(100% - 16px) 0;
  /*And so on ...*/
  background-size:100% 4px,4px 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dtborder ">This text appears inside a double bracket bordered div where you can control the gap between border lines.</div>
```

And also like this too:

```css
.dtborder {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  background:
  /*First border*/
  linear-gradient(red,red) left 0 bottom 0,
  linear-gradient(red,red) 0 0,
  linear-gradient(red,red) 0 0,
  linear-gradient(red,red) right 0 top 0,
  /*Second border*/
  linear-gradient(blue,blue) left 0 bottom 8px,
  linear-gradient(blue,blue) 8px 0,
  linear-gradient(blue,blue) 0 8px,
  linear-gradient(blue,blue) right 8px top 0,
  /*third border*/
  linear-gradient(green,green) left 0 bottom 16px,
  linear-gradient(green,green) 16px 0,
  linear-gradient(green,green) 0 16px,
  linear-gradient(green,green) right 16px top 0;
  /*And so on ...*/
  background-size:100% 4px,4px 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dtborder ">This text appears inside a double bracket bordered div where you can control the gap between border lines.</div>
```

Comment: @Paulie_D yes sure ;) but i thought it's better to separate them so it can be easy to add more .. as with this separation we can handle the colors easily :)

Answer (score 1):

Here I try to figure out some thing like your image, hope this approach help you..thanks

```css
.dtborder {
  position: relative;
  border: 5px solid red;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background: #f8f8f8;
  padding: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.dtborder:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  background: blue;
}

.dtborder:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 100%;
  background: blue;
}

.dtborder_two:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 100%;
  background: blue;
}
.dtborder_two:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  background: blue;
}

.dtborder_three:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 15px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #36648b;
}
.dtborder_three:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 15px;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  background: #36648b;
}

.dtborder_four:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  background: #36648b;
}

.dtborder_four:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 15px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #36648b;
}
```

```html
<div class="dtborder">
  <div class="dtborder_two">
    <div class="dtborder_three">
      <div class="dtborder_four">
        This text appears inside a double bracket bordered div where you can control the gap between border lines.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```